# I have a problem with WP_Rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a problem with RewriteCond. I admit that I don't know how to use these directives (or maybe I haven't searched enough).

I have a URI like this:

```
/photos=the-most-appreciated-books-about-fashion-worth-reading&id=2450&photo=3919
```

Each time you click on the picture, another picture is uploaded.

id = page id
photo = photo id

How can I change this ugly path into something more beautiful, like this:

```
/gallery/the-most-appreciated-fashion-books-worth-reading-id2450-photo3919.html
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about [`.htaccess`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/) rewriting, or WordPress's [Rewrite API](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/rewrite/)?

Comment: Where is this `RewriteCond` directive you are having a problem with? With the URL you posted, there would be no need for a `RewriteCond` directive, since there is no apparent query string? However, to change the URL and make it look more "beautiful", you wouldn't use `RewriteCond` anyway - not with WordPress.

Comment: I studied a little more.
I would like to use WP_Rewrite. (Rewrite API)